# Is there a way to check (from code) if django migrations have been executed?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, migration, prometheus

with:

```
./manage.py showmigrations
```

one sees the list of executed and pending migrations. I'd like to get this list (or number of migrations) at runtime so that I can expose it via a monitoring tool to see if any migrations failed.

I checked the internals, but can't find any way to expose this for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `MigrationRecorder`:

```
from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder

all_migrations = MigrationRecorder.Migration.objects.all()
```

`Migration` is a standard Django model, for example:

`applied_migrations = [migration for migration in all_migrations if migration.applied]`.

That should probably be enough to get you started.

Comment: Oh excellent! I also found out that you can filter by app like:
```app_migrations = MigrationRecorder.Migration.objects.filter(app="xyz")```
thanks a lot!